# Python iterparse large XML while filtering with elements and children

Tags: python, xml, xml.etree, iterparse

I am attempting to parse product data from icecat. The data comes in large xml files. (3-7gb).

In order to reduce the amount of product data I am bringing in, I need to filter this list before moving to my next step. Particularly I need to filter by the "Updated" and "On_Market" values in the "file" element, and IF the "Country_Markets" child exists, I need to see if that (possible) list of children contains <"Country_Market = "US">

I am able to get the On_Market filter to work, but can't figure out how to structure the check of the Country_Markets child, or implement the date filter.

Where I am currently:

**PYTHON:**

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import iterparse

file_path = 'index.xml'
dict_list = []
date = "20220803143328"

for _, elem in iterparse(file_path, events=("end",)):
    for child in elem:
        print(child)
        if child.tag == 'Country_Markets':
            if child.attrib['Country_Market'] == "US" OR child['Country_Markets'] is None:
                if elem.tag == "file":
                    if elem.attrib['On_Market'] == "1":
                        if elem.attrib['Updated']>= date: 
                            dict_list.append({'IceId': elem.attrib['Product_ID'],
                                            'LastUpdate': elem.attrib['Updated'],
                                            'PartNum': elem.attrib['Prod_ID'],
                                            'OnMarket': elem.attrib['On_Market']})

        elem.clear()


df = pd.DataFrame(dict_list)
```

***EDIT***
NEW PYTHON APPROACH

I am trying to implement a different package which seems to do the trick, except I haven't been able to figure out how to incorporate the EAN_UPCS into my output...

```
from lxml import etree

context = etree.iterparse(file_path,  events=("start", "end"),)
for event, elem in context:
    if elem.tag == 'file':
        for child1 in elem:
            if child1.tag == 'Country_Markets':
                for child2 in child1:
                    if child2.attrib['Value'] == "US":
                        if elem.attrib['On_Market'] == "1":
                            if elem.attrib['Updated']>= "20220803143328":
                                print(f"'IceId': {elem.attrib['Product_ID']}")
                                print(f"'LastUpdate': {elem.attrib['Updated']}")
                                print(f"'PartNum': {elem.attrib['Prod_ID']}")
                                print(f"'OnMarket': {elem.attrib['On_Market']}")

                                if child1.tag == 'EAN_UPCS':
                                    for child2 in child1:
                                        if child2.attrib['IsApproved']  == "1":
                                            print(child2.attrib['Value'])
```

**EDIT 2:**

I can get the result I am after if I run segments of the loop, but once I run the entire loop, I either lose information, or append all information.

```
dict_list = []

context = etree.iterparse(file_path,  events=("end",))
for event, elem in context:
    if elem.tag == 'file':
        id = elem.attrib['Product_ID']
        print(id)
        valid = "no"
        dist = ()
        last_date = ()
        market = ()
        upc_list = []
        if elem.attrib['On_Market'] == "1":
            market = "yes"
        if elem.attrib['Updated']>= "20170803143328":
            last_date = "yes"
        for child1 in elem:
            if child1.tag =='Country_Markets': 
                print('markets found')
                for child2 in child1:
                    if child2.attrib['Value'] == "US":
                        dist = "yes"
                        
                    else:
                        if dist != "yes":
                            dist = "no"
                    #had to come up with a way to not overwrite the distibution while iterating throug elements        
            elif elem.find("Country_Markets") is None:
                print("No Markets")
                dist = "yes"
         
            if child1.tag == 'EAN_UPCS':
                    for child2 in child1:
                        if child2.attrib['IsApproved']  == "1":
                            upc_list.append(child2.attrib['Value'])
                   
            
        print(id, dist, last_date, market, upc_list)     
        if dist == "yes" and  last_date == "yes" and market == "yes":   
            dict_list.append({elem.attrib['Product_ID']:{'PartNum':elem.attrib['Prod_ID'], 'Updated' : elem.attrib['Updated'], 'UPCs': upc_list}} )
        continue
    elem.clear()
del context

dict_list
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ICECAT-interface SYSTEM "https://data.icecat.biz/dtd/files.index.dtd">
<!--source: Icecat.biz 2022-->
<ICECAT-interface xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://data.icecat.biz/xsd/files.index.xsd">
    <files.index Generated="20220930000002">
        <file path="export/level4/US/1402.xml" Limited="No" HighPic="https://images.icecat.biz/img/gallery/1402_9631004284.jpg" HighPicSize="744457" HighPicWidth="2670" HighPicHeight="1407" Product_ID="1402" Updated="20220212085227" Quality="ICECAT" Prod_ID="C4893A" Supplier_id="1" Catid="377" On_Market="1" Model_Name="80 Value Pack 350-ml Yellow DesignJet Ink Cartridge and Printhead" Product_View="92380" Date_Added="20051028000000">
            <Country_Markets>
                <Country_Market Value="BE"/>
                <Country_Market Value="FR"/>
                <Country_Market Value="US"/>
                <Country_Market Value="GB"/>
                <Country_Market Value="DE"/>
                <Country_Market Value="CH"/>
                <Country_Market Value="IT"/>
                <Country_Market Value="CA"/>
            </Country_Markets>
        </file>
        <file path="export/level4/US/1414.xml" Limited="No" HighPic="https://images.icecat.biz/img/norm/high/1414-HP.jpg" HighPicSize="43288" HighPicWidth="400" HighPicHeight="400" Product_ID="1414" Updated="20220711134129" Quality="ICECAT" Prod_ID="C6614NE" Supplier_id="1" Catid="377" On_Market="1" Model_Name="C6614NE" Product_View="98879" Date_Added="20051023000000">
        </file>
        <file path="export/level4/US/1415.xml" Limited="No" HighPic="https://images.icecat.biz/img/norm/high/1415-HP.jpg" HighPicSize="43235" HighPicWidth="400" HighPicHeight="400" Product_ID="1415" Updated="20190404035203" Quality="ICECAT" Prod_ID="51650CE" Supplier_id="1" Catid="377" On_Market="1" Model_Name="50 Cyan Inkjet Print Cartridge" Product_View="60706" Date_Added="20051023000000">
            <EAN_UPCS>
                <EAN_UPC Value="0088698200223" IsApproved="0" Format="GTIN-13"/>
                <EAN_UPC Value="088698200223" IsApproved="0" Format="GTIN-12"/>
            </EAN_UPCS>
            <Country_Markets>
                <Country_Market Value="BE"/>
                <Country_Market Value="DE"/>
                <Country_Market Value="IT"/>
                <Country_Market Value="UA"/>
                <Country_Market Value="DZ"/>
            </Country_Markets>
        </file>
        <file path="export/level4/US/7966778.xml" Limited="No" HighPic="https://inishop.com/img/norm/high/7966778-4280.jpg" HighPicSize="814349" HighPicWidth="2761" HighPicHeight="1600" Product_ID="7966778" Updated="20201106094740" Quality="ICECAT" Prod_ID="AX3U1600XC2G79-3X" Supplier_id="2634" Catid="911" On_Market="1" Model_Name="XPG Xtreme Series, DDR3, 1600 MHz, CL7, 6GB (2GB x 3)" Product_View="7328" Date_Added="20110223000000">
            <EAN_UPCS>
                <EAN_UPC Value="4713435791172" IsApproved="1" Format="GTIN-13"/>
            </EAN_UPCS>
            <Country_Markets>
                <Country_Market Value="US"/>
            </Country_Markets>
        </file>
        <file path="export/level4/US/7966779.xml" Limited="No" HighPic="https://inishop.com/img/norm/high/7966778-4280.jpg" HighPicSize="793195" HighPicWidth="2761" HighPicHeight="1600" Product_ID="7966779" Updated="20201106094740" Quality="ICECAT" Prod_ID="AX3U1600XC4G79-3X" Supplier_id="2634" Catid="911" On_Market="1" Model_Name="XPG Xtreme Series, DDR3, 1600 MHz, CL7, 6GB (2GB x 3)" Product_View="6515" Date_Added="20110223000000">
            <EAN_UPCS>
                <EAN_UPC Value="4713435791714" IsApproved="1" Format="GTIN-13"/>
            </EAN_UPCS>
            <Country_Markets>
                <Country_Market Value="LU"/>
                <Country_Market Value="CH"/>
            </Country_Markets>
        </file>
        <file path="export/level4/US/7966780.xml" Limited="No" HighPic="https://inishop.com/img/norm/high/7966780-2331.jpg" HighPicSize="724700" HighPicWidth="2761" HighPicHeight="1600" Product_ID="7966780" Updated="20201106094740" Quality="ICECAT" Prod_ID="AX3U1600XC4G79-2X" Supplier_id="2634" Catid="911" On_Market="1" Model_Name="XPG Xtreme Series, DDR3, 1600 MHz, CL7, 8GB (4GB x 2)" Product_View="6902" Date_Added="20110223000000">
            <EAN_UPCS>
                <EAN_UPC Value="4713435791707" IsApproved="1" Format="GTIN-13"/>
            </EAN_UPCS>
            <Country_Markets>
                <Country_Market Value="LU"/>
                <Country_Market Value="CH"/>
            </Country_Markets>
        </file>
    </files.index>
</ICECAT-interface>
```

The goal is to be able to filter out any items that are older than a certain date, not on market, and explicitly not for sale in the US.  (Items that don't have Country_Markets elements are to be included in the output.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this adjusted `iterparse` approach without the inner loops across child elements. Below uses flag variables to be turned on and off conditionally while walking down the tree. A dictionary of data is built and iteratively appended within  `<file>...</file>` context.

```py
from lxml import etree 
#from xml.etree import ElementTree as etree

file_path = "Input.xml"
files_data = []

context = etree.iterparse(file_path,  events=("start", "end"),)
for event, elem in context:
    if event == "start":
        if elem.tag == 'file':
            data = {}
            US_Flag = 0
            Date_Flag = 0
            if elem.attrib['Updated'] >= "20220803143328":
                Date_Flag = 1
                data['IceId'] = elem.attrib['Product_ID']
                data['LastUpdate'] = elem.attrib['Updated']
                data['PartNum'] = elem.attrib['Prod_ID']
                data['OnMarket'] = elem.attrib['On_Market']
                data['EAN_UPCS'] = []

        if elem.tag == "EAN_UPC" and Date_Flag == 1:
            if elem.attrib['IsApproved'] == "1":
                data['EAN_UPCS'].append(elem.attrib['Value'])

        if elem.tag == "Country_Market" and Date_Flag == 1:
            data['Country_Market'] = "US"
            if elem.attrib["Value"] == "US":
                US_Flag = 1

    if event == "end":
        if elem.tag == "file" and (US_Flag == 1 or "Country_Market" not in data):
            files_data.append(data)

        elem.clear()
```

**Output**

*For demonstration, below results remove `>= "20220803143328"` condition since posted XML does not contain dates in that range*

```py
from pprint import pprint

pprint(files_data)
[{'Country_Market': 'US',
  'EAN_UPCS': [],
  'IceId': '1402',
  'LastUpdate': '20220212085227',
  'OnMarket': '1',
  'PartNum': 'C4893A'},
 {'EAN_UPCS': [],
  'IceId': '1414',
  'LastUpdate': '20220711134129',
  'OnMarket': '1',
  'PartNum': 'C6614NE'},
 {'Country_Market': 'US',
  'EAN_UPCS': ['4713435791172'],
  'IceId': '7966778',
  'LastUpdate': '20201106094740',
  'OnMarket': '1',
  'PartNum': 'AX3U1600XC2G79-3X'}]
```

Comment: This is really close to what I am currently working on! I am banging my head against the keyboard because my loops are tripping me up.  I'll post where I'm at and give this a spin as well.  Thanks for giving it another shot!

Comment: I made a couple of tweaks. I added the On_Market check to the date check if statement, and I added the Date_Flag as an additional condition in the if statement for appending data. (To remove blank rows that were coming through.)  That gives the desired result on my demo set. Currently running it against the real data.

Comment: First attempt caused a memory crash pretty quick.  Added elem.clear() to last line of loop and attempting again.

Comment: Adding the elem.clear() did the trick.  It parsed through the ~7 million records in  ~7.5 minutes and returned ~1.75 million results

Comment: Whoops! Forgot that very important line inside the last `if` block. Just [added](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73938362/revisions). Glad it worked as needed. Happy coding!

Comment: I do have a question.  This line:  "data['Country_Market'] = "US" seems to be out of place? It is being set without actually checking for a child with that market.  It wasn't a big deal because I don't actually need that data in my return, so I commented that line out.  When I do that, it causes the returned data to be a much larger set of data. (Currently trying to track down why.)

Comment: Correction, it also happens when I comment out "data['OnMarket'] = elem.attrib['On_Market']"  I guess I am missing something here. Why would commenting out either of these lines cause the loop to return more products?

Comment: The first line (not second) is used as conditional on last `if`: `"Country_Market" not in data`. This is to capture cases where this element does not exist, hence why we assign a dictionary element even if not needed for your final purpose. Also, we avoid any child checking here since `iterparse` runs through all start and end points of every element. We flag any instance "US" shows and if no `Country_Market` element exists.

Comment: That makes sense for the data['Country_Market'] bit if it's just a placeholder. (The flag is what makes sure the incorrect items don't come through.)  But I don't undertand why commenting out the data['OnMarket'] would cause the same issue. That one has me stumped.

Answer (score 1):

Consider iterparsing the entire XML and then filter afterwards to avoid the logic checks while traversing the varying designs of the `<file>` elements. One way can be with your use of pandas.

Specifically, try the *new* [large XML support](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.5.0.html#read-xml-now-supports-large-xml-using-iterparse) (which uses `iterparse` with either lxml and etree parsers) introduced in current v1.5 with the relatively new [**`pandas.read_xml`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html) IO method. See [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-read-xml) showing at end the parsing of Wikipedia's 12 GB+ XML dump in minutes (tested on a 8 GB RAM laptop)!

Also in v1.5, `read_xml` now supports [dtype handling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.5.0.html#read-xml-now-supports-dtype-converters-and-parse-dates) like other IO modules (i.e., `read_csv`, `read_json`) such as converting the `Updated` attribute value to datetime. You can even rename columns accordingly:

```py
import pandas as pd

products_df = pd.read_xml(
    "Input.xml",
    iterparse = {"file": ["Product_ID", "Updated", "Prod_ID", "On_Market"]},
    names = ["IceID", "LastUpdate", "PartNum", "OnMarket"],
    parse_dates = ["LastUpdate"]
)

print(products_df)
#      IceID          LastUpdate            PartNum  OnMarket
# 0     1402 2022-02-12 08:52:27             C4893A         1
# 1     1414 2022-07-11 13:41:29            C6614NE         1
# 2     1415 2019-04-04 03:52:03            51650CE         1
# 3  7966778 2020-11-06 09:47:40  AX3U1600XC2G79-3X         1
# 4  7966779 2020-11-06 09:47:40  AX3U1600XC4G79-3X         1
# 5  7966780 2020-11-06 09:47:40  AX3U1600XC4G79-2X         1

print(products_df.dtypes)
# IceID                  int64
# LastUpdate    datetime64[ns]
# PartNum               object
# OnMarket               int64
# dtype: object
```

Since the `@value` attribute is used multiple times for `EAN` and `Country_Market` elements, you need to repeat with generalized renaming. Below parses the first 15 `@value` elements under `<file>` element. Notice, `read_xml` drops all missing value columns since only max of 8 `@value` is ever used!

```py
products_df = pd.read_xml(
    "Input.xml",
    iterparse={
        "file": [
            "Product_ID", "Updated", "Prod_ID", "On_Market",
            "Value", "Value", "Value", "Value", "Value",
            "Value", "Value", "Value", "Value", "Value",
            "Value", "Value", "Value", "Value", "Value"
        ]
    },
    names = [
        "IceID", "LastUpdate", "PartNum", "OnMarket", 
        "Value_1", "Value_2", "Value_3", "Value_4", "Value_5",
        "Value_6", "Value_7", "Value_8", "Value_9", "Value_10",        
        "Value_11", "Value_12", "Value_13", "Value_14", "Value_15",
    ],
    parse_dates = ["LastUpdate"]
)

print(products_df)
#      IceID          LastUpdate            PartNum  OnMarket        Value_1       Value_2 Value_3 Value_4 Value_5 Value_6 Value_7 Value_8
# 0     1402 2022-02-12 08:52:27             C4893A         1             BE            FR      US      GB      DE      CH      IT      CA
# 1     1414 2022-07-11 13:41:29            C6614NE         1           None          None    None    None    None    None    None    None
# 2     1415 2019-04-04 03:52:03            51650CE         1  0088698200223  088698200223      BE      DE      IT      UA      DZ    None
# 3  7966778 2020-11-06 09:47:40  AX3U1600XC2G79-3X         1  4713435791172            US    None    None    None    None    None    None
# 4  7966779 2020-11-06 09:47:40  AX3U1600XC4G79-3X         1  4713435791714            LU      CH    None    None    None    None    None
# 5  7966780 2020-11-06 09:47:40  AX3U1600XC4G79-2X         1  4713435791707            LU      CH    None    None    None    None    None

print(products_df.dtypes)
# IceID                  int64
# LastUpdate    datetime64[ns]
# PartNum               object
# OnMarket               int64
# Value_1               object
# Value_2               object
# Value_3               object
# Value_4               object
# Value_5               object
# Value_6               object
# Value_7               object
# Value_8               object
# dtype: object
```

From there, consider various pandas methods (`DataFrame.loc`, `DataFrame.query`, etc.) to filter data by `LastUpdate` date, `OnMarket` values, and any `'US'` or all empty two-character fields. Possibly reshape to long with `DataFrame.melt` to separate and capture `EAN` values.

Comment: I can't attempt implementing this yet, but it's exciting to see that pandas has that feature now.  I did come up with an iterparse solution that worked on smaller test data, but it crashes when I try to run it against the full file.   Do you think that pandas will have any memory issues when trying to parse in 6 million products?  -- I'll report back once I can give this a shot!

Comment: Yes, please give it a try. Run `pip install pandas --upgrade` to v1.5 as needed. As author of this IO module, I can attest what I mentioned above that `iterparse` allowed an 8 GB RAM laptop to parse Wikipedia's 12 GB XML daily dump to a 3.6 mill-row  data frame in about 5 minutes with either `lxml` or `etree` parsers (i.e., XML was larger than RAM)! Your crashing may be due to all the logic checks that ideally should run after parsing data.

Comment: I can run the first version while bumping up against the 8gb limit of my instance. The second version however rides the 8gb usage and ultimately crashes. (The first example creates a dataframe with 6.9 million rows.)

Comment: Interesting use case. Restart CPU and try re-running with no other opened apps including browsers and ideally run .py script only with python.exe at command line (without IDEs like Spyder or Jupyter). At end of script, save data frames as compressed pickles for use later. But this may be due to nested complexity of your XML. `@value` columns may be many across entire document. `iterparse` may not be memory-intensive but `pandas` operations to build DataFrame from parsed data.